# Retrieve browser and OS in PHP

Tags: php, browser, operating-system

I need to retrieve the browser and OS through php coding.

I had used `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, but its shows the following

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; IEMB3)
```

How can I separate the browser and OS from the above received value?

Please guide me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to point out that using something like $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] is not reliable, as users can change their UA at will.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Google code Browscap class](http://code.google.com/p/phpbrowscap/). It essentially does the same thing as PHP's get_browser(), but you don't have to worry about keeping your browscap.ini up to date.

This worked for me:

```
require('Browscap.php');
$browscap = new Browscap('/path/to/cache');
var_dump($browscap->getBrowser());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the built in function for this http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

Grab a copy of [browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/) compare $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] with that file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be using the buil-in get_browser() function as it's a few times faster than the Google-Code-version if you're only running it once. (If you're running it 4+ times the Google-Code-version is faster)

So unless you need the auto-update and only use one check at a time, you should use the built-in version. :)

And it shouldn't be that hard to make a cronjob to get the newest version. ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can use simple explode();

```
<?php
$ex=explode(' ',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
echo 'OS: '.$ex[4].' '.$ex[5].' '.$ex[6].'/n'; 
echo 'Browser: '.$ex[0]; 
?>
```